# How to set keyboard s-up to go move cursor to start of buffer in emacs (and s-down to move cursor to end of buffer)?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

What can I add to my `init.el` to move the cursor to the very first character of the open buffer when I press `s-up` (i.e. hold "command" key, press "up" key on macOS), and equivalent for `s-down`?

I know it should be something like `(global-set-key (kbd "s-<up>") ... )`

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [emacs.se] or [su].

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight. My understanding is that emacs is primarily used for programming, and therefore this post is not off-topic for StackOverflow. I see that emacs has its own StackExchange community though so that's helpful, thanks.

Comment: Emacs is used for editing (and other things, such as web browsing, and reading news and mail).  Simply because some of the files you edit may be programs doesn't make it a special-purpose programming tool.  Emacs questions can be on-topic if they are about extending Emacs itself (usually by writing Emacs Lisp functions) or about specific programming modes.  Otherwise (and perhaps also in those cases), you're likely to get better help from the specialists over on [Emacs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<up>")   'beginning-of-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<down>") 'end-of-buffer)
```

You can find out what command a given key is bound to by using `C-h k`.

In this case, `M-<` takes you to the beginning of the buffer, and `C-h k M-<` tells you this:

> **`M-<`** runs the command `beginning-of-buffer`, which is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `simple.el`.
>
> It is bound to `begin`, `C-home`, `M-<`, `menu-bar search goto beg-of-buf`.
>
> `(beginning-of-buffer &optional ARG)`
>
> Move point to the beginning of the buffer.
>
> With numeric arg `N`, put point `N`/10 of the way from the beginning.
>
> If the buffer is narrowed, this command uses the beginning of the
>   accessible part of the buffer.
>
> If Transient Mark mode is disabled, leave mark at previous
>   position, unless a `C-u` prefix is supplied.
>
> Don't use this command in Lisp programs!
>   `(goto-char (point-min))` is faster.

Similarly, for `M->`, which is bound to `end-of-buffer`.